# I am getting Reference error:checkout not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button named checkout.But onclick i'm getting this error : Reference error:checkout not defined 
My button code is :

```
<input type="button" value="Checkout" title="Checkout" class="button checkout" onclick="checkout()">
```

When i click on the button i want to show user-info

javascript code is:

```
$(function(){
  $('.add-cart').html('+');

  function checkout(){
   $('.cart-status').hide(slow);
   $('.user-info').show(slow);
  }
});
```

Comment: what js have u included ?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout is defined inside another function so it is not accessible from the global scope. You can put it in the global scope:

```
$(function () {
    $('.add-cart').html('+');
});

function checkout() {
    $('.cart-status').hide('slow');
    $('.user-info').show('slow');
}
```

But a better solution is to stop putting event handlers in your HTML markup:

```
<input type="button" value="Checkout" title="Checkout" class="button checkout" />
```

```js
$(function(){
    function checkout() {
        $('.cart-status').hide('slow');
        $('.user-info').show('slow');
    }

    $('.add-cart').html('+');
    $('.button.checkout').click(checkout);
});
```

(Note: Another problem in your code was that you were using the undefined variable `slow` instead of the string value `'slow'`, but scoping was preventing `checkout()` from being called at all.)